# "Bundle" synonym

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Are there any synonyms for "bundle" that mean anything like "multiple items together" (apart from package, parcel, etc.) For example, a discounted SOMETHING of two products on a website.

"bunch", for example, won't work because you wouldn't go say "I'm going to buy the DVD bunch at the store" (at least not as often or in the same way as "bundle"). Similar thing with "clump", "roll", etc. and all the other synonyms Google, for example, provides.

I have a problem with "bundle" because of external circumstances not related to the word itself, so it's a prime example of what I mean (I just can't use it).

Comment: Hi, at ELU a minimum of personnal research is expected. Did you  try to google it, what are the results, why don't they suit you ?

Comment: bunch, roll, clump, wad, parcel, sheaf, bale, bolt, package, pile, stack, heap, mass.  And that's just what Google found when I typed "bundle synonym".

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain what is wrong with bundle.

Comment: @curiousdannii like that?

Answer (score 1):

Would these do?

> "I'm going to buy the DVD **set** at the store"
>
> "I'm going to buy the DVD **collection** at the store"

[ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=DVD%20set%2CDVD%20collection%2CDVD%20bunch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDVD%20set%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDVD%20collection%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

pack, packet, accumulation, array, assortment, bag, batch, box, carton, cluster, crate, pallet, pile, quantity, stack, collection, group, lot, **set**, multiplicity, number (of), band, assemblage, aggregation, store, **medley**, conglomeration, collation, **miscellany**

and my personal favorite a *congeries*, which is only second to a *caboodle* :)

hope this helped, I searched far and wide

P.S. I love your username!! I watched The Hobbit-tbotfa last night :)

Comment: Thanks :) These don't really work, however, since stores wouldn't be advertising a DVD "assemblage", for example....

Comment: I am shocked!  Shocked, I say! Do you mean a threesome?  "Bundling, or tarrying, was the traditional practice of wrapping one person in a bed accompanied by another, usually as a part of courting behavior. The tradition is thought to have originated either in the Netherlands or in the British Isles and later became common in Colonial America, especially in Pennsylvania Dutch Country. When used for courtship, the aim was to allow intimacy without sexual intercourse."  Wikipedia